# Mailgun sending attachment with RestSharp

Tags: c#, attachment, email-attachments, restsharp, mailgun

I'm using RestSharp to try and send an attachment with the Mailgun API. I have tried attaching from both a file in the system using a hardcoded path and also from a binary file stored in the database using `ToArray()` method on the `varbinary(MAX)` (SQL Server) property both with no success.

The attachment *technically sends*, but when the email arrives in my inbox the file size is always roughly 302bytes big and is always corrupt. I have tried 3 different files and get the same problem each time.

The rest of the email sends, delivers and displays fine. It's just the attachments that are broken.

Breakdown of code:

```
// Doesnt work(Data property is varbinary(MAX)
request.AddFileBytes("attachment",databaseModel.Data.ToArray(),databaseModel.Filename, "multipart/form-data");

// Also doesnt work(Data property is varbinary(MAX)
request.AddFile("attachment",databaseModel.Data.ToArray(),databaseModel.Filename, "multipart/form-data");

// Also doesnt work        
var path = @"D:\Template.pdf";
request.AddFile("attachment",path,"multipart/form-data");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out..

Not supposed to add "multipart/form-data" on the request.AddFile();

Removing this fixes the problem.

Comment: I tried using - request.AddFile("attachment", Path.Combine(path1,fileName), "multipart/form-data") and it is working fine. Thanks - @Sinmok

Answer (score 17):

This code works:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(SendSimpleMessage().Content.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static IRestResponse SendSimpleMessage()
{
    var path1 = @"C:\Users\User\Pictures\website preview";
    var fileName = "Learn.png";
    RestClient client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
    client.Authenticator =
        new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api",
                                    "key-934345306fead7de0296ec2fb96a143");
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    request.AddParameter("domain", "mydomain.info", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
    request.AddParameter("from", "Excited User <example@mydomain.info>");
    request.AddParameter("to", "peter.cech@gmail.com");        
    request.AddParameter("subject", "Hello");
    request.AddParameter("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness! This is all about the text only. Just testing the text of this email.";
    request.AddFile("attachment", Path.Combine(path1,fileName));
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    return client.Execute(request);
}
```

Comment: Good job! Really helpful!

Comment: Didn't try it out, but wanted to leave a note just in case you posted your real life API key by accident. Thanks for the answer!